# Enable 32 bit applications set to True with teamcity and octopus deployment

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I use team city for build and octopus for deployment.

After each deployment, Enable 32 bit applications in app pool is set to True though Enable 32 bit applications is set to false in octopus and this started happening suddenly.

I want Enable 32 bit applications in app pool to be False.

Tried couple of ways but couldn't figure out what's going on.

Anyone faced similar issue or have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old version of the "IIS AppPool - Create" step template had a bug with the way it handled some booleans, causing `Enable32BitAppOnWin64` and `AutoStart`  to always be `True`.  Try updating to the latest version of the step template from https://library.octopusdeploy.com/#!/step-template/actiontemplate-iis-apppool-create.  The relevant lines in the script are for parsing the parameters:

```
$appPoolAutoStart = [boolean]::Parse($OctopusParameters['AppPoolAutoStart'])
$appPoolEnable32BitAppOnWin64 = [boolean]::Parse($OctopusParameters['AppPoolEnable32BitAppOnWin64'])
```